# Is there a function or hook I can use to keep track of simple plugin changes in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

Is there a function or hook I can use to keep track of simple plugin changes? Like a type of Audit Log that displays the changes on a "Custom Post Type" type of way ,I know there are different type of plugins I can use but I was wondering if it's possible to add a function or create my own log instead to only track the time of a change for example:

> "Name of Plugin" "DD/MM/YY Time" "Updated" or "Deleted" or "Activated" or "Deactivated"

Something like this? I'm searching for a function or I'm not sure exactly what to call it myself that might do this instead of a plugin because I want it to be as simple as possible without the extra content the plugins provide

Comment: What about the [deactivated_plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/deactivated_plugin/), [activated_plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/activated_plugin/) and [deleted_plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/deleted_plugin/) hooks? Couldn't find anything about updated though.

Comment: Ohhh I shall try these out I had no idea about this thank you